# Displaying an animated PNG (apng) using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, png, gif, apng

I'm trying to display an animated png (known as `apng`), by adding the image to a `JLabel` as usual. This works fine with normal `gif`-animations, however, I'd prefer to be able to support `apng` aswell.

I've been searching the net for existing frameworks or solutions for this, finding nothing. Has anyone else found a way to display animated pngs in Swing?

To understand why I want to implement `apng`, view the following example which demonstrates GIF's limitations: http://jsfiddle.net/RUX8w/ *(your browser must support apng!)*

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much support for APNG in Java at the moment.  Most examples I found required you to physically read the file yourself, which is a lot of additional overhead...

Comment: APNG is not standard PNG

Comment: 'The way' would be to add an SPI for APNG to the run-time class-path of the app.  Given the comment of @leonbloy though, I doubt you will find an existing SPI.

Comment: @leonbloy I understand that. You don't know of any "API" which implements it anyway?

Comment: @Zar: No, I've been looking into it (perhaps to include support in my  PNGJ library), but frankly I disliked its approach. But there might exist other libraries.

Comment: @leonbloy Hmm, okay. I'll keep on looking. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thought so as well, sadly. Thanks anyways, though.

Comment: Did you find a way to display apng in Swing?

Comment: @André No, I went with a simple GIF instead.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google for "apng Java" turned up http://code.google.com/p/javapng and in particular, http://code.google.com/p/javapng/source/browse/trunk/javapng2/src/apng/com/sixlegs/png/AnimatedPngImage.java?r=300